# How to save/restore value on CustomLayoutManager?

Tags: android, linearlayoutmanager

Currently, I am using custom LinearLayoutManger(StackLayoutManager) which save and retrieve some int value for my RecyclerView as below code,

```
@Override
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(KEY_TOTAL_OFFSET, mTotalOffset);
    bundle.putParcelable(KEY_SUPER_SAVED_STATE, super.onSaveInstanceState());
    return bundle;
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    if (state instanceof Bundle) {
        Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
        mTotalOffset = bundle.getInt(KEY_TOTAL_OFFSET, 0);
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable(KEY_SUPER_SAVED_STATE));
    }
}
```

some times its throws error when geting int on `onRestoreInstanceState`  as bellow,

```
Class not found when unmarshalling: android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$SavedState
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$SavedState
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2889)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2843)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2746)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3115)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:273)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:226)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.getInt(BaseBundle.java:993)
    at app.example.com.ui.StackLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(StackLayoutManager.java:113)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onRestoreInstanceState(RecyclerView.java:1397)
    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:17850)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchThawSelfOnly(ViewGroup.java:3769)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(RecyclerView.java:1414)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3755)
    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:17828)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:494)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1486)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3269)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
    at app.example.com.ui .DashboardActivity.onStart(DashboardActivity.java:227)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1413)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7061)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2874)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2989)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I searched but I could not find any solution regarding my issue